# Error: In laravel 8 with passport 10 after running composer update command

Tags: laravel

I have an error while creating passport token in laravel 8 with passport package 10. Everything is working properly before running composer update command. When I run the composer update command I got this error:-

```
message: "Method Laravel\Passport\Bridge\AccessToken::__toString() must not throw an 
          exception, caught ErrorException: Using integers for registered date claims is 
          deprecated, please use DateTimeImmutable objects instead."
exception: "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError"
```

Please help while resolving this error. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1380 looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Current solution is downgrade lcobucci/jwt package.

```
composer require lcobucci/jwt:3.3.3
```

Also you can check this https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1380

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have also got the solution on github repo.